# Linq2sql join query to show list of names but only show ones that have record in another table

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

I have an employee table and I am currently filling the combo box with the names in that table. I also have related table called expenseHdr that contains the employee pk. My table structure looks like this:

```
employees     expenseHdr
empPk         expPk
name          expenseType
              empPk
```

Right now it is filtering the names but it is repeating the name for each record it has in the expenseHdr. How would I get it to only display each name once? Thanks!

```
var emps = (from emp in db.employees
                        join exp in db.expenseHdrs on emp.pk equals exp.empPk
                        where emp.active == true 
                        orderby emp.name
                        select emp.name.Substring(0, 20)).ToList();
            cboEmployee.DataSource = emps;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Any()`

```
var emps = (from emp in db.employees
                        where emp.active && emp.expenseHdrs.Any()
                        orderby emp.name
                        select emp.name.Substring(0, 20)).ToList();
            cboEmployee.DataSource = emps;
```

If there is no db relation between the tables you would instead write:

```
where emp.active && db.expenseHdrs.Any(exp => emp.pk == exp.empPk)
```

Comment: where emp.active && db.expenseHdrs.Any(exp => emp.pk == exp.empPk) What would this be without using lambda?

Comment: emp.active && (from x in db.expenseHdrs where x.pk == exp.empPk select x).Any()

Comment: there are times lambda is shorter and elegant, this is one of those. Use lambda instead, it is shorter and as readable